# Access and modify a protected field

Tags: java, reflection

I'm recently working on a project and I need to access a protected variable in another class. This is the code that I used:

```
 FieldUtils.writeField(world.getClass(), "chunkProvider", provider, true);
```

,but when I try to run my code I get this error: https://hastebin.com/hoqeralasa.md .

As you can easily understand the error is telling me that the field is not there but if I check the target class, I can see it:

```
protected IChunkProvider chunkProvider;
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS:
The FieldUtils class comes from  org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.FieldUtils;

Comment: can you post more code? seems that you have some other error here too.

Comment: seems duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362497/why-cant-i-access-a-protected-variable-in-java-this-way

Comment: Yes what classes would you like to see?

Comment: No that's not the question I asked

Comment: @AlessandroAutiero just code above that writeField invoke, so I can see where you get that world, provider etc.

Comment: @GotoFinal https://hastebin.com/hegoxahezo.java

Comment: ah, luis answer is correct here, that method requires object, not a class. Also note that reflections are slow, you should cache them if code is executed often. So just get a field instance once and use it later.

Comment: you don't even use that utils in that code...

Comment: @GotoFinal That method is executed just one time

Comment: @GotoFinal Oh ya, I changed it to try something else

Comment: So go back to older code and use luis answer, and if it works then upvote and accept his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you put your code??...maybe you can try with:

FieldUtils.writeField(world, "chunkProvider", provider, true);